# Session variables not sticking with GXT

Tags: grails, macos, gxt, gwt2

I'm encountering a strange problem with the session using GXT 2.1 and a Grails 1.2 backend. I'm creating two `FormPanel`s, `panelA` and `panelB`, which submit to `action1` and `action2` in Grails respectively. In action1 I set a hardcoded session variable and retrieve it in action2, but it is always returning null! If I manually go to action1 then follow by going to action2 in a browser it works exactly as expected. I've tried running on both Firefox and Safari in development mode and get the same result on both. Any ideas on what I should look for? Some relevant snippets:

In GXT:

```
final FormPanel panelA = new FormPanel();
panelA.setVisible(false);
panelA.setAction(action1);
panelA.setMethod(Method.POST);
RootPanel.get().add(panelA);
panelA.submit();
```

In Grails:

```
def a1 = {
  session.a1 = "Hello A1"
  println "Set A1 to $session.a1"
  render "Set A1 to $session.a1"
}

def a2 = {
  println "From A2, A1 is set to: $session.a1"
  render "From A2, A1 is set to: $session.a1"
}
```

Comment: Looks like it has to do with the proxyservlet I'm using to get around the cross domain issues at development time. Any suggestions to get that to work with my session as a client would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of cross domain form posts and JSON-P as a solution, it's a great workaround as I can just post the form (with a transaction id), store any feedback/results in the session, then retrieve that data using a JSON-P call.